# Extract data from NDSolveValue result

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

Okay this is a very newbie question. I have coded a sample problem that solves the heat diffusion equation on an annulus. Here's what I have:

```
Dom = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1 && x^2 + y^2 <= 5, {x, y}];
C = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 200., x^2 + y^2 == 1], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., x^2 + y^2 == 5]};

result = NDSolveValue[{\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) ==  0, C}, u, {x, y} \[Element] Dom];
```

I can plot the data as a contour plot. All that is good. Now, say I want to get the mean of the temperature. How I do that? I imagine the data is contained in the variable 'result', but it is very opaque to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NIntegrate` to do that, like this

```
NIntegrate[result[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Dom]/
  NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] Dom] // Chop // AbsoluteTiming
(*74.23246590163654`*)
```

`Chop` is nessary because the result contains a very small imaginary part

[image]

I'm sorry for that I don't know why these warnings occurs, but it seems harmless.

There is another way which can avoid the warnings but give a result with larger error and spend more time

```
dom = DiscretizeRegion[Dom, AccuracyGoal -> 2];
NIntegrate[result[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] dom]/
 NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] dom]
(*74.8653680261704`*)
```

Chose larger `AccuaryGoal` can improve the accuary of the result, but costs more time

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Dom = ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 >= 1 && x^2 + y^2 <= 5, {x, y}];

c = {
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 200, x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 5]};

result = NDSolveValue[{\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) ==  0, c}, 
   u, {x, y} \[Element] Dom];

GraphicsRow[{
  ContourPlot[result[x, y],
   {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]},
   {y, -Sqrt[5 - x^2], Sqrt[5 - x^2]},
   PlotPoints -> 75,
   Contours -> Range[0, 200, 25],
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature",
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{x, y, z}, Dom[[1]]]],
  Plot3D[result[x, y],
   {x, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5]},
   {y, -Sqrt[5 - x^2], Sqrt[5 - x^2]},
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature",
   RegionFunction ->
    Function[{x, y, z}, Dom[[1]]]]},
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

The area is given by `RegionMeasure[Dom]`

```
avg = NIntegrate[result[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Dom]/
   RegionMeasure[Dom] // Quiet
```

> 74.2325